# Learning Flash Programming for PHP Websites

Tags: flash

Any pointers where i could start learning flash programming.
Also i would be really grateful if you could point me to place where i could get free templates for the programming

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you tagged php? Is you come from a php background? BTW, it will be useful if you tell us what programming background do you have.

Comment: I'm basically a asp.net developer ... sorry to tag it with Php .. it was by mistake

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=flash+programming

Comment: I don't think there is one single book or website dedicated to Flash in the world so I'm not surprised you couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to learn Flash (as3) programming then you want to get [Essential Actionscript 3 by Colin Moock](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946).

There is a lot of AS3 code out there. You will have to be more specific regarding your goals to really provide an answer. "Flash Programming" is extremely general. Flash IDE, AS3, Flex, etc...

Comment: I want to develop a website using flash and php, I want to learn it that way.

Comment: If you want to learn Flash programming, you need to learn the language (as3), if you want the hack at templates...

Answer (score 0):

Using the [AMFPHP framework](http://www.amfphp.org/) you will be able to make remote call from actionscript to your php back-end methods. The site has a lot of good example to get you started. Basically, this framework helps you serialize object from the [Action Message Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) to it's php equivalent. For example, you will be able to send and/or receive arrays inside your actionscript code.

If you want to work with a .NET back-end, [FluorineFx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) is an excellent open-source option. Some very good examples are included in the download package. You can subscribe to mailing-list and receive direct help from Zoli (creator of the framework).

Let us know if that helps you.